# Example of Two Improper Integrals Whose Product Improper Integral Diverges

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Consider two functions f(x) and g(x) such that they are continuous on [1,$\infty$) and $\int_{1}^{\infty}$ f(x) dx converges and $\int_{1}^{\infty}$ g(x) dx converges and $\int_{1}^{\infty}$ f(x)g(x) dx diverges.

Does anyone have any examples of f(x) and g(x) that fit such criteria, I'm having trouble thinking of such examples thanks.

Comment: You may try to start from $f(x)=g(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x^p}$ and to pick $p$ nicely.

Comment: Thanks I found an example now.

Comment: Just curious, what example did you find?

Comment: f(x) = g(x) = sin(x)/sqrt(x) converges on [1 ,inf) but f(x)g(x) = sin^2(x)/x diverges on [1,inf)